# Convert older inner join query to new code

Tags: sql

please convert this older inner query to new inner join query.

```
"SELECT m.*, s.*, pt.* FROM tbl_mcate m, tbl_scate s, tbl_producttype pt where pt.scate_id=s.scate_id and m.mcate_id=s.mcate_id";
```

Comment: Next time, do an attempt by yourself before asking. And show it if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy one:

```
SELECT m.*, s.*, pt.* 
FROM tbl_mcate m 
        inner join tbl_scate s on  m.mcate_id=s.mcate_id 
        inner join tbl_producttype pt on pt.scate_id=s.scate_id
```